# Setting default parent item in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, routes, nodes

In Drupal 7 it is possible to set a **default parent item** at admin/structure/types/manage/article/edit.

[image: screenshot]

Where is this option in Drupal 6?

If it isn't possible to do this in Drupal 6, is there a contributed module that will achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Node Menu Parent](http://drupal.org/project/node_menu_parent) is the module you need to achieve this:

> The Node Menu Parent module gives us an extra option under the content
>   type settings to choose a specific parent menu item per content type.